# здравствуйте не получается спарсить rrs новость , почему то не забирается кодом

Tags: php, парсер

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

 $rss = simplexml_load_file("http://static.feed.rbc.ru/rbc/logical/footer/news.rss");
//var_dump($rss);
  foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {

   $title=$item->title;
   echo "TITLE =  ".$title."<br>";
  }

?>
```

пишет Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\work.php on line 8

короч он не может  взять  страницу это функцией simplexml_load_file("http://static.feed.rbc.ru/rbc/logical/footer/news.rss");
там пусто
helllp me!!!

Comment: Тут точно что-то итерируемое находится `$rss->channel->item`?

Comment: $rss в том  то и дело  тут ничего  нет  в этой переменной ,а должно  быть  файл c rss страницей

Comment: может  он  по http не может  взять этой функцией simplexml_load_file() ,а только  https?

Comment: Судя по описанию https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.simplexml-load-file.php тут ожидается файл, а не URL. Загрузите страницу, например через cURL, после распарсите через `DOMDocument`. после у объекта DOM документа вызовете `query` передав xpath запрос типа `//channel/item` результат в цикле переберете

Comment: спасибо,попробую так сделать,но в видио я симотрел, там url кидали

Comment: еще я пробывал  file_get_contents() функцию  применить  тоже не получилось , хотя https://www.php.net/ парсит

Comment: потому что в "видио" файл парсился с помощью simplexml_load_file() видимо с локального хоста, с того же самого где расположен скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что указанный сайт возвращает неверный формат RSS.

Содержимое RSS ленты представлено в виде XML документа, соответственно и тип данного документа должен быть `Content-type: text/xml`, на указанном же сайте `Content-type` указан как `document`, что совершенно не верно.

Из-за того, что указан неверный формат, не указано, что это XML ваш PHP скрипт попросту не может получить доступ к элементам на странице, из-за этого переменная `$rss` пуста и вам выводиться пустой результат.

Как вариант можно распарить страницу с помощью сURL, но в данной ситуации это будет костылем, так как указанный сайт предоставляет данные в неверном формате.